# Python inheritance, metaclasses and type() function

Tags: python, class, python-import, abc

I can't understand why the following code behaves a particular way, which is described below:

```
from abc import ABCMeta   

class PackageClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta        

class MyClass1(PackageClass):
    pass

MyClass2 = type('MyClass2', (PackageClass, ), {})

print MyClass1
print MyClass2

>>> <class '__main__.MyClass1'> 
>>> <class 'abc.MyClass2'>
```

Why does `repr(MyClass2)` says `abc.MyClass2` (which is by the way not true)?
Thank you!

Comment: The project structure seems to be completely irrelevant here.  I would advise removing that part and just having it all as 1 module (the described behavior is still there).

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for noticing, updated.

Comment: And, as a side note, this behavior still holds in python3.x (I just tested it)

Comment: @mgilson It does not on my system - I get `<class '__main__.MyClass2'>
.` with cpython 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3.

Comment: @phihag -- Are you using python3 style metaclasses?  `class PackageClass(metaclass = ABCMeta): pass`?

Comment: Simpler testcase: `type('bar', (ABCMeta('foo', (object,), {}),), {})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that `ABCMeta` overrides `__new__` and calls its superclass constructor (`type()`) there. `type()` derives the `__module__` for the new class from its calling context<sup>1</sup>; in this case, the `type` call appears to come from the `abc` module. Hence, the new class has `__module__` set to `abc` (since `type()` has no way of knowing that the actual class construction took place in `__main__`).

The easy way around is to just set `__module__` yourself after creating the type:

```
MyClass2 = type('MyClass2', (PackageClass, ), {})
MyClass2.__module__ = __name__
```

I would also recommend filing a bug report.

Related: [Base metaclass overriding __new__ generates classes with a wrong __module__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209521/base-metaclass-overriding-new-generates-classes-with-a-wrong-module), [Weird inheritance with metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124129/weird-inheritance-with-metaclasses)

1: `type` is a type object defined in C. Its [new method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9009178e08d9/Objects/typeobject.c#l1978) uses the current global `__name__` as the `__module__`, *unless* it calls a metaclass constructor.